# как узнать длинну строки в пикселях?

Tags: qt, qpainter, qt6

Раньше я так узнавал длину строки в пикселях (работал в куте 5.12)

```
QFont razm_shrift("Areal", _myTexpr.m_t_razm[7]*2.4, QFont::Light);         // свойства шрифта
painter.setFont(razm_shrift);                                               // устанавливаем размер шрифта
QFontMetrics stroka_razm = painter.fontMetrics();                           // метрика шрифта

_myTexpr.nadp1 = "Строка"
  
_myTexpr.m_t_razm[8] = stroka_razm.width(_myTexpr.nadp1);               // узнаём ширину строки
```

Теперь я так не могу делать ж_ж (куте 6.2)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как теперь надо делать ??? 0_о

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открываем документацию на "парную функцию" [height](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-1) и там есть ответ -

> If you want to know the advance width of the string (to lay out a set of strings next to each other), use horizontalAdvance() instead.

Собственно, Вам нужна функция horizontalAdvance.

Comment: `_myTexpr.m_t_razm[8] = stroka_razm.horizontalAdvance(_myTexpr.nadp1);   // узнаём ширину строки` - пример